# how can I arrange my textViews with reference to screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, percentage

I have 15 textView elements and I want to align as one under the other. But when the screen size narrow, some textViews disappear. How can I arrange this? (I've been using RelativeLayout. If there is a solving with others Layouts, you can explain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create you own layout.

This layout will auto flow the next line if there is not enough space.
Like float:left in html/css

```
public class PredicateLayout extends ViewGroup {

    private int line_height;

    public PredicateLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public PredicateLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        assert(MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec) != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);

        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        // The next line is WRONG!!! Doesn't take into account requested MeasureSpec mode!
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
        final int count = getChildCount();
        int line_height = 0;

        int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
        int ypos = getPaddingTop();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                child.measure(
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));

                final int childw = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                line_height = Math.max(line_height, child.getMeasuredHeight() + lp.height);

                if (xpos + childw > width) {
                    xpos = getPaddingLeft();
                    ypos += line_height;
                }

                xpos += childw + lp.width;
            }
        }
        this.line_height = line_height;

        if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED){
            height = ypos + line_height;

        } else if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST){
            if (ypos + line_height < height){
                height = ypos + line_height;
            }
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(30, 30); // default of 1px spacing
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(LayoutParams p) {
        return (p instanceof LayoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int  r, int b) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        final int width = r - l;
        int xpos = getPaddingLeft();
        int ypos = getPaddingTop();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getVisibility() != GONE) {
                final int childw = child.getMeasuredWidth();
                final int childh = child.getMeasuredHeight();
                final LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
                if (xpos + childw > width) {
                    xpos = getPaddingLeft();
                    ypos += line_height;
                }
                child.layout(xpos, ypos, xpos + childw, ypos + childh);
                xpos += childw + lp.width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> But when the screen size narrow, some textViews disappear. How can I
>   arrange this?

Use a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) to make the UI scrollable.

Comment: Ahmad is correct, you want to wrap your layout in ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks..Can I fixed without `ScrollView` ?